# HBase Multiple PrefixFilters + setLimit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I have a list of row prefixes. I'd like to query N rows for each prefix.

I can't use MultiRowRangeFilter because I don't know what is the ending rowkey prefix for the range. Neither can I use scan.setLimit(N) as I think it'll limit the **total** number of rows queried to N (what I wanted is for **each prefix** to have N rows).

My current setup:

```
val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
// set zookeeper quorum properties in hbaseConf

val hbaseContext = new HBaseContext(sc, hbaseConf)

val rowPrefixes = Array("a", "b", "c")
val filterList = new FilterList()

rowPrefixes.foreach { x => filterList.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes(x))) }

var scan = new Scan()  

scan.setFilter(filterList)
scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("myCF"));

val rdd = hbaseContext.hbaseRDD(TableName.valueOf("tableName"), scan)
rdd.mapPartitions(populateCaseClass)
```

I'm not sure which filter should I use to achieve this multiple rowkey prefixes + setLimit for each rowkey...

Comment: you need custom mapper that would count how many times each prefix matched. there's no standard setting for that.
also, FilterList default behaviour is MUST_PASS_ALL, change it to MUST_PASS_ANY

Comment: Adding to @AdamSkywalker comment, a single prefix could span across two (or even more) regions - hence multiple spark partitions - so you must have an additional step to filter top N results for each prefix.